# Object File name contains ':' path delimiter on Firefox

Tags: javascript, file, path, blob, separator

I'm working on an Angular 6 project and I'm facing a problem with Firefox (63.0) on MacOS High Sierra.

At some point, I load a file from my assets as a File object. Later I retrieve the File name property. On Chrome, the file name uses slashes (/) as path separator and on Firefox it uses colon (:) as path separator.

The file is loaded as follow:

- An HTTP GET is performed to get the resource as a Blob;
- The Blob is converted to a file using: `new File([blob], fileName)`, where fileName is a string representing the file path using slashes (e.g.: `fileName = 'path/to/my/file.txt'`)

I have been able to reproduce the bug in the console by running the following commands:

```
var blob = new Blob();
var file = new File([blob], 'path/to/my/file.txt');
```

The resulting objects are different on Chrome and Firefox:

- On Chrome
  [image: Console output on Chrome]
- On Firefox
  [image: Console output on Firefox]

My questions are:

Is that a normal behavior of the File constructor to convert the file name differently depending on the browser?

If yes, how should I handle this behavior to prevent my file name to have different path separators on different browsers?

Comment: `File.name` is not a pathName, but a file name. So you will probably even have different outputs on different systems. And to prevent this, don't use common path separators in your file name. What is it you were trying to do exactly with this path?

Comment: You're right, we shouldn't use the `File.name` to store the file path. We used that file path to check if the file was loaded from a local file (by comparing the File.name to that local file path). But this is not a good way of achieving this.
I was curious about why different browsers were implementing the File object constructor differently though.

Comment: It turns out that this behaviour is actually part of the spec, so it looks like Firefox implements it correctly and some other browser don't:
https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#file-constructor